# how can I use win32print to print a file without changing the default printer?

Tags: python, pywin32

Good afternoon! I can't print a document if the printer is not installed by default on windows 10.
I tried to change the default printer before printing and return it back, but without result. It changes the default printer and returns it back without printing the file. How can this be fixed?

```
type here
        if error.exec() == QMessageBox.Ok:
            printer_1 = ""
            printer_1 = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
            filename = 'text_print.txt'
            printers = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)
            printer_name = ""
            for printer in printers:
                if printer[2] == printer1:
                    printer_name = printer[2]
                    break

            win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer_name)
            handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
            win32print.StartDocPrinter(handle, 1, (filename, None, 'RAW'))
            win32print.StartPagePrinter(handle)
# Печатаем определенное количество копий
            for _ in range(copies):
                win32api.ShellExecute(0, 'print', filename, None, '.', 0)
                self.comboBox_gc2.setCurrentIndex(0)
                    # Завершаем печать и закрываем документ
            win32print.EndPagePrinter(handle)
            win32print.EndDocPrinter(handle)
            win32print.ClosePrinter(handle)
            win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printer_1)
```

I tried to change the default printer before printing and return it back, but without result. It changes the default printer and returns it back without printing the file. How can this be fixed?